# Is it possible to use 'return' instead of 'echo' to output a wpdb query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have this working function meant to be used for a WordPress Multisite Database query. It's perfectly okay but I want to know if it is possible to output the desired results using `return` instead of `echo`.

Every solution and example I've come across uses `echo`.

```
function akwQueries_byMembership( $memID ){
    switch_to_blog( akw_memSiteID() );
    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $membershipTable = $prefix.'membership_users_table';
    $query="SELECT members_id, status
        FROM $membershipTable
        WHERE members_id=$memID AND user_id=$user_id AND status='active'";
    $req_memid=$wpdb->get_row($query);
    if( $req_memid !== null ){
        // My question arises from here...
        echo 'Good to go';
    } else {
        echo 'Not ok';
    }
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

I tried using `return` and it's so lifeless. I would love, for instance, to return `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the restore function up above the return statement and then return the boolean.

```
function akwQueries_byMembership( $memID ){
    switch_to_blog( akw_memSiteID() );
    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $membershipTable = $prefix.'membership_users_table';

    $query="SELECT members_id, status
        FROM $membershipTable
        WHERE members_id=$memID AND user_id=$user_id AND status='active'";

    $req_memid=$wpdb->get_row( $query );

    restore_current_blog();

    return $req_memid !== null;
}
```